# Extend an existing stream collector instance

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need a Collector that's nearly identical to `Collectors.toSet()`, but with a custom finisher.  I'd love to be able to do something like:

```
myCollector = Collectors.toSet();
myCollector.setFinisher(myCustomFinisher);
```

and be done, but that doesn't seem possible.  The only alternative I can see is it essentially recreate `Collectors.toSet()` using `Collector.of()`, which is not very DRY.

Is there a way to take an existing Collector and amend it as described above?

EDIT

A few of the answers have recommended something like this:

```
  Collector<T, ?, Set<T>> toSet = Collectors.toSet();
  return Collector.of(
     toSet.supplier(),
     toSet.accumulator(),
     toSet.combiner(),
     yourFinisher,
     toSet.characteristics());
```

However my custom finisher isn't actually returning a Set; it's using the accumulated set to return something else.  The fact that it's doing that is putting me into Generics hell which I'm still rummaging through..

Comment: It's not the most ideal solution, but you could probably create a wrapper class for `Collectors` where you would implement the `setFinisher`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That’s exactly what [`collectingAndThen(collector,finisher)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) does.

The custom finisher does not replace the old one, if there is one, but gets combined with it (like [`oldFinisher.andThen(newFinisher)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-)), but the current implementation of `toSet()` has no finisher (an identity finisher) anyway.

So all you have to do, is `collectingAndThen(toSet(),myCustomFinisher)`…

Answer (score 4):

This is the implementation for a `toSet` basically:

```
 Collector.of(
            HashSet::new,
            Set::add,
            (left, right) -> {
                left.addAll(right);
                return left;
            });
```

All you have to do is add `UNORDERED` Characteristics and your finisher. Looks fairly trivial to be honest. *OR* look at Holger's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Taking the title of your question literally, you cannot achieve what you want by "extending" a `Collector` that returns a `Set`, because the third generic type parameter of `Collector` specifies "the result type of the reduction operation", so a `Collector<?,?,R>` can never be a subclass of `Collector<?,?,Set>`, unless R implements `Set`.

I don't know what you want to do with the `Set` as a finishing function, neither do I know the type of the elements in your `Set`, so let's assume, for the sake of simplicity, that you are streaming over `String`s and you want to check the number of unique `String`s in the stream by returning the size of the resulting `Set<String>`.

The type of your `Collector` would have to be `Collector<String, ?, Integer>`, so you won't get around this declaration (the fact that you want to determine the number of unique `String`s via a `Set<String>` is irrelevant, hence the second parameter can be `?`).

Now, naturally, you want to take advantage of `Collectors.toSet()`. But how? A `Collector` has 4 functions, a supplier, an accumulator, a combiner, and a finisher. From these 4, it seems like you could use the first 3 of the `Collector` returned by `Collectors.toSet()`. Now here's the rub: The return type of `Collectors.toSet()` is actually `Collector<T, ?, Set<T>>`, with the second type parameter, `?`, which denotes the accumulation type, being the problem. To explain this in non-generic terms: You have no way of knowing how the `Collector` accumulates the elements internally. You only know that the *finishing* function will return a `Set`. However, this does not necessarily mean that the items will be accumulated in a `Set`. For all you know, the `Collector` could accumulate the items in a `List` and only at the finishing stage create a `Set` from the `List`'s content. On the other hand, the finishing function of your custom `Collector`, which calculates the size of a `Set`, expects a `Set` as an input value, but the `Collector` returned by `Collectors.toSet()` cannot guarantee that it accumulates the elements into a `Set`.

Unfortunately, this means that, if you want to create a custom `Collector` that accumulates the stream elements into a `Set` and returns the size of this `Set` at the finishing stage (or does whatever else you want to do with the `Set`), the colletor returned by `Collectors.toSet()` is effectively useless, since all three of the `supplier`, `accumulator` and `combiner` pararmeters of `Collector.of(Supplier, BiConsumer, BinaryOperator, Function, Collector.Characteristics)` depend on the accumulation type, which is not known of `Collectors.toSet()`.

So the most viable solution seems to me to create a helper method that first collects the stream elements into a `Set` using `Collectors.toSet()`, and then performs the finishing transformation manually. Reading Holger's answer, it seems like a method that does this already exists.